# F# forward pipe to convert from int to bigint

Tags: f#

I am fairly new to F# and came up across this scenario and was hoping someone could explain why my compiler doesnt like the code...

If in F# I do the following...

```
let FloatToInt = 10.0 |> int
let IntToFloat = 10 |> float
```

Everything is fine and the number is cast to the relevant data type...

if however I do the following...

```
let IntToBigInt = 10 |> bigint
```

I get a error "Invalid use of type name or object constructor."
I assume that this is because there isnt an operator overload for the forward pipe for bigint?

If I wanted to make this code possible, how would I do it? I know I could use different syntax like...

```
let IntToBigInt = bigint(10)
```

But I really like the Forward Pipe syntax and would like to know if I can achieve it so that...

```
let IntToBigInt = 10 |> bigint
```

would work...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It has nothing to do with overloads. `10.0 |> int` works because there is a function named `int`. There is however no function named `bigint`, so `10 |> bigint` does not work.

If you define one, it works:

```
> let bigint (x:int) = bigint(x);; // looks recursive, but isn't
val bigint : int -> System.Numerics.BigInteger

> 42 |> bigint;;
val it : System.Numerics.BigInteger = 42I
```

Comment: To add to sepp's, the `bigint` Mark was using before is a type constructor, not a function.

Comment: if you REALLY want to use pipeline then...
let y = 1 |> bigint.op_Implicit

Comment: How could I create a generic conversion funtion that works with all types?