# How to use pipe-forwarding in my file read code

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am new to F#, If I am asking this at the wrong place, please do let me know.

I have the following sequence for reading files

```
let readFile (filePath : string) = seq {
let reader = new StreamReader(filePath)
while not reader.EndOfStream do
    yield reader.ReadLine ()
}
```

I learned about pipe-forwarding operator and how code looks so functional and easy to read with it, I am trying to convert the above to use pipe-forwarding operator, In other words I want to go pipe-forward crazy. Here is what I have written so far. Please tell me where I am doing it wrong or if I shouldn't be using it in this scenario.

```
let readFilePipe (filePath : string) = seq {
filePath
|> new StreamReader
|> while not reader.EndOfStream do
    yield reader.ReadLine()
    }
```

The above code won't compile. Also if you have a list of scenarios where Pipe-forwarding operator should not be used, I would be glad if you shared those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two outstanding issues here:

1. The pipe operator cannot be used with class constructors. It can be used with static methods, but again, with some limitations;
2. You have to dispose the `StreamReader` in a nice manner by using `use` keyword. Hence, pipe appears to be useless here.

The shortest code is:

```
let readFile (filePath : string) = seq {
    use reader = new StreamReader(filePath)
    while not reader.EndOfStream do
        yield reader.ReadLine()
}
```

---

TL;DR

The reason why the pipe operator can't be used effectively with class constructors is because of constructors are usually overloaded, so if it were supported it could ruin type inference. See other questions on this matter: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111774/can-i-use-the-pipeline-operator-in-f-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-constructor), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531178/using-the-f-pipe-symbol-with-an-object-constructor), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158554/f-forward-pipe-to-convert-from-int-to-bigint).

This snippet shows the problem:

```
type A (x:int) = class end
let a1 = new A 5    // works
let a2 = 5 |> new A // does not compile: Incomplete structured construct 
                    // at or before this point in expression
```

If you really, really want pipe to be used with a class constructor, you may either write a small function or an extension method (if the class is not `sealed`), but again, they are useless in your case because of need to use `use` keyword.

```
// plain function
let makeStreamReader (filePath : string) = new StreamReader(filePath)
// and use
let sr1 = filePath |> makeStreamReader

// extension method
type System.IO.StreamReader with
    static member Make (filePath : string) = new StreamReader(filePath)
// and use
let sr2 = filePath |> StreamReader.Make
```

Comment: Well, if you don't need deterministic resource cleanup, you could skip the `use` and let the garbage collector clean it up.

Comment: @Christopher : Technically true, but leaving a file handle open is almost always a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine:

```
filePath
|> new StreamReader
```

this is not:

```
|> new StreamReader
|> while not reader.EndOfStream do
    yield reader.ReadLine()
```

You need to think about what the `|>` is doing - the `while` isn't a function, so it doesn't make sense to use the pipe operator here.

The canonical examples are doing things like:

```
filepath
|> new StreamReader
|> processData
|> ...
```

Comment: How come pipe does not work for string.Split ?

let s = "something,somethingelse"
s |> string.Split [|','|]
wont compile, why ?

Comment: because `string.Split` takes has the form `String.Split (a,b)` not `String.Split a b`

Comment: You would need a lambda wrapper in that case `|> (fun arg -> String.Split([|','|],arg))`.

Comment: There's also [Core.FuncCovert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee340268(v=vs.100).aspx) if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the symbol `reader` is never bound.

The `|>` operator takes the value on the left and applies it to a function on the right:

```
let (|>) a (f:'a -> 'b) = f a
```

Since a while loop is not a function, this doesn't quite work. Put another way, the `|>` operator is best suited for functional style code not imperative. Fortunately, the resulting `readFilePipe` function itself facilitates the functional style.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but...

```
let streamToSeq (sr : StreamReader) = seq {
    while not sr.EndOfStream do
    yield sr.ReadLine()
}
let readFilePipe (filePath : string) =
    new StreamReader(filePath)
    |> streamToSeq
```